# Amazon Elastic Transcoder - Adding duration to output returning error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm using AWS SDK PHP.

Using `->createJob(` everything is fine, but when I add

```
'Composition' => array(
                    'TimeSpan' => array(
                        'StartTime' => '00:00:00.000',
                        'Duration' => '00:00:02.000'
                    )
                )
```

to one of the outputs, I get the following error:

> {"error":{"type":"Aws\ElasticTranscoder\Exception\ElasticTranscoderException","message":"Start of structure or map found where not expected.","file":"/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/breves/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php","line":91}}

I'm trying to cut the video.

Any toughts?

[Amazon SDK API Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/create-job.html)

Answer (score 5):

Found out the answer:

it should be an array of "clips", like so:

```
'Composition' => array(
array(
    'TimeSpan' => array(
        'StartTime' => '00:00:00.000',
        'Duration' => '00:00:02.000'
    )
```

)

In my case I only needed 1 clip.

**More information about duration here:**
**(Optional) Clip Start Time** - (StartTime)
You can create an output file that contains an excerpt from the input file. Clip Start Time indicates the place in the input file where you want a clip to start. The format can be either HH:mm:ss.SSS (maximum value: 23:59:59.999; SSS is thousandths of a second) or sssss.SSS (maximum value: 86399.999). If you don't specify a value, Elastic Transcoder starts at the beginning of the input file.

**(Optional) Clip Duration** (Duration)
The duration of your excerpt clip. The format can be either HH:mm:ss.SSS (maximum value: 23:59:59.999; SSS is thousandths of a second) or sssss.SSS (maximum value: 86399.999). If you don't specify a value, Elastic Transcoder clips from Clip Start Time to the end of the file.

If you specify a value longer than the duration of the input file, Elastic Transcoder transcodes from Clip Start Time to the end of the file and returns a warning message.

For Detailed info about aws transcoder [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/job-settings.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an answer to add a little more information to the solution to this problem.

> You can use Amazon Elastic Transcoder to generate partial excerpts of
>   content, or
>   ["clips,"](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/11/08/amazon-elastic-transcoder-introduces-clip-generation/) from your source media.

As @jplozano mentioned in his followup, he should only have a single clip for each source file. Here is an excerpt from the [Amazon Elastic Transcoder API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/create-job.html)

```
"Composition":[
        {
           "TimeSpan":
              {
                 "StartTime":"starting place of the clip, in
                    HH:mm:ss.SSS or sssss.SSS",
                 "Duration":"duration of the clip, in HH:mm:ss.SSS
                    or sssss.SSS"
              }
        }
```

> The Composition object contains settings for the *clips* that make up
>   an output file. Currently, **you can specify settings for only a
>   single clip** per output file. The Composition object cannot be null.
>   All jobs in a playlist must have the same clip settings.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work. I keep on getting errors about "Message":"Start of list found where not expected"